# Which apps support the vga adapter for iPad 1?

Tags: ipad, vga-adapter

iPad 2 supports full mirroring, which is great, but I have an iPad 1. How do I find out which apps support the vga adapter on iPad 1. I have failed to find a definitive answer.

For example maps, safari, google earth, photos.

I have seen references to video and itunes supporting it, but not fully.

Which apps have you used with the VGA adapter, and which features does it support?

Comment: This question is much too broad. There is no definitive answer.

Comment: I was hoping for a whole series of definitive answers of the form 'app x supports it and displays y and z on the vga output'. I hadn't anticipated receiving a single answer that says 'works ok'

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it, Sketchbookx, Bamboo paper and pdf-notes work with iPad1 (not jailbroken) with VGA connector.

Answer (score 0):

Keynote does, and works ok.

Beyond that I would not expect that any app supports it unless explicitly noted in the app's description.

It takes extra effort for the developer to support VGA output, so unless they see a market for it, they usually won't do. Even then usually you don't have the same view on your VGA screen as on your iPad.

Comment: I have yet to find an app that clearly states what it supports on the iPad 1 vga output. Even keynote only vaguely mentions the adapter, with nothing specific on the iPad 1, and some reports suggest it only works when playing a slideshow.